# Can you save the same variables in a list?

Tags: python

I would like to assign several identical variables to a list. The variables must be named the same because of my script.

```
list = []
filter = input("Eingabe")
filter = input("Eingabe")
list.append(filter)
print(list)
```

Is selected for input 1 and 2. Is the output:

```
['2']
```

That is still clear to me. How must the code be changed so that the output is a list of 1 and 2 ? So like this:

```
['1','2']
```

Comment: You're not assigning variables to a list. You're assigning a reference to a string, then overwriting it. What's preventing you from appending after the first input? The name of the variable shouldn't matter

Comment: "The variables must be named the same because of my script." I have no idea what this is supposed to mean, but you cannot have two different variables with the same name - they are the same variable. There should be no reason why you can't just use a different name each time, but that also has nothing to do with solving the problem. If you want to put two things into the list using `.append`, then the `.append` has to be used two times.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want this

```
l = []

while len(l) < 2:
    f = input('Eingabe')
    l.append(f)
    
print(l)
```